# mongorestore error Failed: EOF when restore DB from dump.gz

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack, mongodump, mongorestore

I am getting error while importing DB backup using **mongorestore** command with **dump.gz**

Using following command to restore DB:

```
mongorestore --gzip --archive=dump.gz --nsInclude=MyApp
```

Getting following error:

```
2019-12-04T14:14:40.352+0530    Failed: EOF
2019-12-04T14:14:40.352+0530    0 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.
```

What is wrong with this command?

Answer (score 0):

--nsInclude="MyApp" syntax is wrong

Try for example:
Syntax:

```html
mongorestore --nsInclude=dbName.collectionName
```

You can also restore a specific collection or collections from the dump/ directory. For example, the following operation restores a single collection from corresponding data files in the dump/ directory:

**mongorestore --nsInclude=test.purchaseorders dump/**

If the dump/ directory does not contain the corresponding data file for the specified namespace, no data will be restored. For example, the following specifies a collection namespace that does not have a corresponding data in the dump/ directory:

**mongorestore --nsInclude=foo.bar dump/**